# How to edit CSS styles in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

**So for example I can do this:**

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('element').style.color = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

**But how should I do this?**

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('element').style.-moz-box-shadow = '1px 1px 1px #000'; 

}
```

I hope you get what I mean :)

Please do not post any answer related with jQuery or any library, I want it in plain javascript.

Comment: Why are you trying to edit the style directly, rather than modify classes? You're just building in brittle browser awareness.

Comment: `-moz-box-shadow` has nothing to do with CSS3. See the vendor-specific prefix? That means it's non-standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's:

```
myobject.MozBoxShadow = '1px 1px 1px #000';
```

It doesn't follow the "typical" formatting of a style object (which would lower-case the "M") because of the initial "-" character. Converting between style properties and JS properties for those styles means:

1. Converting the first character to lower case
2. Converting all characters after dashes to upper case
3. Removing all dashes

Thus, "-moz-box-shadow" becomes:

1. -moz-box-shadow (the first character is a "-", so it doesn't have a lower case)
2. -Moz-Box-Shadow
3. MozBoxShadow

Comment: Yes it is :D I've found it just right now somewhere, thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you change '-' to a capital letter, so:

```
 document.getElementById('element').style.-moz-box-shadow = 1px 1px 1px #000;
```

Should be:

```
  document.getElementById('element').style.MozBoxShadow = "1px 1px 1px #000";
```