# Edit multiple CSS styles using a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556619/how-to-edit-css-styles-in-javascript) on editing css styles in Javascript, in which the solution is to use

```
document.getElementById('element').style.MozBoxShadow = "1px 1px 1px #000";
```

I am trying to write a function that takes an array of parameters to edit as so:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
editElementStyles(element, new Array("width", "100%", "height", "100%"...etc.));
```

And the function:

```
function editElementStyles(element, args) {
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
        element.style.args[i] = args[i + 1];
    }   
}
```

However, this of course does not work as `args[i]` is not a property of `element.style`. How can I make this work?

Comment: I am open to JQuery, but would prefer not to go there.

Comment: FYI, `new Array(elem1, elem2, elem3, ...)` can be expressed more simply as `[elem1, elem2, elem3, ...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
element.style[args[i]] = args[i + 1];
```

You correctly note that `args[i]`, and `args`, is not a property of `element.style`, to counter this you simply use square-bracket notation, rather than dot-notation, to access the properties. Which, incidentally, you were doing with `args[i]` anyway.

This results in:

```
function editElementStyles(element, args) {
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
        element.style[args[i]] = args[i + 1];
    }   
}
```

Incidentally, this seems to be a risky way of associating properties and values; I'd suggest:

```
function editElementStyles (element, styles) {
    for (var prop in styles) {
        if (styles.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            element.style[prop] = styles[prop];
        }
    }
}

editElementStyles (elem, {'width' : '100%', 'color' : 'red'});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change your function to accept an object since what you are really looking for is a key/value pair

```
editElementStyles(element, {"width" : "100%", "height" : "100%"});


function editElementStyles(element, args) {
    for (var key in args) {
        element.style[key] = args[key]
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the square bracket notation instead, that allows you to use the value of variables for the property name to look up.

i.e. change your function to:

```
function editElementStyles(element, args) {
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
        element.style[args[i]] = args[i + 1];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

`element.style[args[i]] = args[i+1];`

You can access properties through  `object[property]` as you do with `object.property`.

However as other answers suggests it's better to use a `json` object instead of array to pass the properties names and values.

Comment: That last `.` isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the point notation you can always access such properties in the following ways:

```
man.age=25
```

is equivalent to

```
man['age']=25
```

So, try this

```
element.style[args[i]]= args[i + 1];
```